# R Convert date and hour to time_stamp generates NA for only 1 hour of 1 day

Tags: r, date, time

I am trying to generate a time stamp for an hour which is 0,1,2-23 with a date using as.POSIXct.

as.POSIXct generates NA for hour 1 on the 29th of March, it works as expected for all the other dates February to December 2020.
Also the hour 00 for the 29th shows up GMT instead of BST like all the others.

Below code generates the issue for me, there is a difference in the date create by strptime the date that doesn't work is in GMT and the other is in BST not sure how this would cause an NA for hour 1?

```
#create date combining characters from input file only difference is the 29
#all other dates work as expect using the 30 for example
date_working <- strptime(paste("30","March","2020",sep = "-"), "%d-%B-%Y")
date_not_working <- strptime(paste("29","March","2020",sep = "-"), "%d-%B-%Y")

#hour characters are the same for both NA is only generated for hour "1"
hour <- c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
          "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
          "23")

#Use paste to combine hour, day, month, year with right seperators to get date format for as.POSIXct
time_stamp_working <- as.POSIXct(paste(date_working,paste(hour,"00",sep = ":"),sep = " "), 
                      format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

#Use paste to combine hour, day, month, year with right seperators to get date format for as.POSIXct
time_stamp_not_working <- as.POSIXct(paste(date_not_working,paste(hour,"00",sep = ":"),sep = " "), 
                          format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

The below output shows the issue

```
> time_stamp_working[1:5]
[1] "2020-03-30 00:00:00 BST" "2020-03-30 01:00:00 BST" "2020-03-30 02:00:00 BST"
[4] "2020-03-30 03:00:00 BST" "2020-03-30 04:00:00 BST"
> time_stamp_not_working[1:5]
[1] "2020-03-29 00:00:00 GMT" NA                        "2020-03-29 02:00:00 BST"
[4] "2020-03-29 03:00:00 BST" "2020-03-29 04:00:00 BST"
```

Comment: The time `"2020-03-29 01:00:00 GMT"` simply doesn't exist in your PCs locale. That's when the clocks go forward for British Summertime. The time goes straight from 00:59:59 to 02:00:00. R knows this and won't let you create it. It's like trying to set the date to the 12th of Never - there's no such thing, so you get an NA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by @Allan Cameron daylight savings is applicable for local timezones. The issue could be avoided though if you stay in GMT/UTC timezone.

```
as.POSIXct(paste(date_not_working,paste(hour,"00",sep = ":"),sep = " "), 
           format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = 'GMT')

# [1] "2020-03-29 00:00:00 GMT" "2020-03-29 01:00:00 GMT" "2020-03-29 02:00:00 GMT"
# [4] "2020-03-29 03:00:00 GMT" "2020-03-29 04:00:00 GMT" "2020-03-29 05:00:00 GMT"
# [7] "2020-03-29 06:00:00 GMT" "2020-03-29 07:00:00 GMT" "2020-03-29 08:00:00 GMT"
#[10] "2020-03-29 09:00:00 GMT" "2020-03-29 10:00:00 GMT" "2020-03-29 11:00:00 GMT"
#[13] "2020-03-29 12:00:00 GMT" "2020-03-29 13:00:00 GMT" "2020-03-29 14:00:00 GMT"
#[16] "2020-03-29 15:00:00 GMT" "2020-03-29 16:00:00 GMT" "2020-03-29 17:00:00 GMT"
#[19] "2020-03-29 18:00:00 GMT" "2020-03-29 19:00:00 GMT" "2020-03-29 20:00:00 GMT"
#[22] "2020-03-29 21:00:00 GMT" "2020-03-29 22:00:00 GMT" "2020-03-29 23:00:00 GMT"
```